# Wordpress - AMCharts only display on page reload

Tags: wordpress, svg, reload, amcharts

I am working on adding an SVG map to a page in WordPress. I can display the map with the AMCharts plugin but when I navigate to a new page then back to the page with the map on it, it no longer renders. In the chrome console, I see the code for the map that's generated but it is not visible.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with WordPress and using AMCharts?

I am thinking maybe there's a way to auto reload the page when navigating to the page with the map but I'm not sure how to do that just on first page click.

Any input would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you post a link to your page? It's hard to tell what the problem could be without a way to reproduce it.

Comment: I am running locally but I have a template page that displays the chart I created with the default AMcharts map code and this is what I have in my php page:  `<?php echo do_shortcode("[amcharts id='map-2']"); ?>`

Comment: The issue you're describing sounds like a front-end HTML/CSS/JS problem, which is likely related to how your template is designed. PHP code doesn't help narrow down the problem, unfortunately. A live link to any page of yours that reproduces this would really help in troubleshooting the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with an upgraded theme.